# Creating NuGet using Team Foundation Server missing dependencies

Tags: c#, tfs, nuget, .net-standard-2.0

I have created a simple class library in .net standard 2.0 with a few nuget dependencies like Dapper.

I am using Team Foundation Server 16 to then build and package the project. My issue is, that when I then browse to my new NuGet package, it does not list it's dependencies in the NuGet package manager in VS and I have to install them manually afterwards.

Creating a nuget package of the same class library from Visual Studio 2019 locally works as intended.

My build tasks on TFS are:

1. Use nuget 5.4.0
2. NuGet restore
3. Build solution
4. Run script (A .bat file for updating version number)
5. NuGet pack
6. Publish build artifact

The NuGet pack uses default settings with command "pack" and path pointing only to .csproj file.

Comment: Can you share how do you pack it in TFS?

Comment: It's one issue about `nuget pack` command for new-sdk format projects(.net core, .net standard). For this, you should use `dotnet pack` command. And it means that you should use dotnet pack task instead of nuget pack task in your pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Creating a nuget package of the same class library from Visual Studio
>   2019 locally works as intended.

It's one issue about `nuget pack` command. When you pack the `.net standard` project in VS locally, it(right-click=>**pack** button) actually calls `dotnet cli` instead of `nuget.exe` to do the `pack` job.

For now, `nuget pack` command can't work well with those projects that use `PackageReference` to manage nuget packages. (Including `.net framework` projects with `PackageReference`,`.net core` and `.net standard` projects).

More details see discussions [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5979) and [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4491).

> To resolve that issue(For TFS2017 and above):

Use [dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack) command instead of [nuget pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-pack) command. And for pipeline in tfs, use dotnet restore, build, pack tasks instead of nuget restore, nuget pack tasks.

[image]

**Update1 for TFS2016:**

Since TFS will run those tasks in tfs agents, one alternative way is to install `.net core sdk` manually, and then use [command-line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to execute `dotnet pack` command to create nuget packages.

`.net core sdk` download link [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral).

**Update2:**

Also, we can still use `nuget pack` command/task. To include those dependencies, we need to create an extra [xx.nuspec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec) file with content similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>PackageName</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <authors>xxx</authors>
    <owners>xxx</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">MIT</license>
    <description>xxx</description>
    <releaseNotes>xxx</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency id="Dapper" version="1.30.0"/>
        //define other dependencies manually here. 
   </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Place this file in same directory where `xx.csproj` exists, and then `nuget pack` command/task can now create the package with dependencies.

Comment: I don't see dotnet pack in my list of tasks to add. Is this because we are using TFS version 16?

Comment: @stefan Do you mean tfs2016? According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=tfs-2017), dotnet related task is only available for tfs2017 and above. I can imagine another one or two workarounds for this issue, but it may take some time before I test and then update the answer.

Comment: @stefan Sorry for that not noticing the dotnet related tasks are not available in tfs2016, I add two more alternative workarounds in answer to resolve the issue. Hope it helps  to resolve your issue and feel free to let me know if it persists to block you :)

Comment: Using the .nuspec file in your update 2 worked as intended. Thanks.

Comment: I strongly suggest using the command line task to run `dotnet pack` instead of using a nuspec file. If you ever decide to multi-target your project, `nuget pack` will stop working. If you change the version of dapper, but forget to change the nuspec, your package will have the wrong dependency. If you add other dependencies, you'll have to do so in both your csproj and nuspec. Using `dotnet pack` instead removes all these potential issues.